# md-select with multiple - limit amount of selected showing

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

When using the Angular Material md-select with multiple, every single item selected will be displayed. I have a multiple selector showing counties, and they are all supposed to be pre-selected.
This results in a list containing 30+ items, not looking very nice for the page setup.

Any options that can limit the selections showing after they have been selected?

Is it somehow possible to display the md-select-text when you exceed a limit, in my case 3 or more?

Any other solutions?

[Link](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select) to several codepen examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way of achieving this , but is you just want to display a limited text post selection , you can try the following using `md-selected-text`.

```
<md-select ng-model="selected" placeholder="Pick" ng-change="onChange()" md-on-open="onOpen()" multiple md-selected-text="getSelectedText()">
<!-- OPTIONS -->
</md-select>
```

And in JS:

```
$scope.getSelectedText = function() {
    console.log($scope.selected);
    if ($scope.selected !== undefined) {
        var filtered=filterSelectedItems($scope.selected); //Filter the display string over here
        return filtered
} else {
    return "Please select an item";
}
}
```

The ng-model `selected` in case of `multiple` mode is an array.Iterate over it and display a condensed string.
Further you can put a tooltip over it to display the complete selected items.

Comment: I am getting `ReferenceError: filterSelectedItems is not defined`. Any idea why?

Comment: No . `filterSelectedItems` is the function which you would have to create as per your requirement.Let's say you just want to show the first 3 selected items , then this function will return the first 3 elements of the array.